# function in jquery return undefined when definied in the call of the function

Tags: jquery

in jQuery I would like to use a function for a searching, I want to use a function because I will search on several element.
But when I call my function I have the error :

> TypeError: i.nodeName is undefined[Learn More]
>   jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:67502
>
> val jQuery
>
> search http://localhost/js/searchOption.js:9
>    http://localhost/js/searchOption.js:25 
>   dispatch2jQuery

There is my code :

```
    $(function() {
        /** define of the function search **/
        function search(cells){
            var value = $(this).val(); //line9
            $(".grid").each(function(index) {
                if (index !== 0) {
                    $row = $(this);
                    var id = $row.find(cells).val();
                    if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                        $row.hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $row.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        /** Option for searching by code **/
        $(".ExistingCode").on("keyup", function() {
            search(".cellName"); //line 25
        });
});
```

and here the related php code :

```
<?php foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) { ?>
                <form method="post" >
                    <div id="<?='row'.$ingredient->code()?>" class="grid">
                        <span><input type="text" id="<?='code'.$ingredient->code()?>" class="cellCode" name="code" value='<?=$ingredient->code()?>' readonly></span>
                        <span><input type="text" id="<?='name'.$ingredient->code()?>" class="cellName" name="name" value='<?=$ingredient->name()?>'></span>
                        <span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="codealias" value='<?=$ingredient->codealias()?>'>
                            <button type="submit" id="<?='supplier'.$ingredient->code()?>" class="cellSupplier" name="supplier" value='<?=$ingredient->supplier()?>' formaction="menu.php?Option=SelectSupplierConfig"><?=$ingredient->supplier()?></button>
                        </span>
                        <span><input type="text" id="<?='editdate'.$ingredient->code()?>" class="cellDate" name="editdate" value='<?=$ingredient->editdate()?>' readonly></span>
                        <span class='centeredElement' ><button id='<?=$ingredient->code()?>' class="ButtonEdit" type="button" ></button></span>
                        <span class='centeredElement' ><button class="ButtonDelete" type="button" value='<?=$ingredient->code()?>'></button></span>
                    </div>
                </form>

            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <aside id='search'>
                    <h2> Search </h2>
                    <input type="text" class="ExistingCode" name="Code" placeholder='<?=$ingredients[0]->codealias()?>'> </br>
                    <input type="text" class="ExistingName" name="Name" placeholder='<?=$ingredients[0]->namealias()?>'> </br>
                    <input type="text" class="ExistingSupplier" name="supplier" placeholder='<?=$ingredients[0]->supplieralias()?>'> 

            </aside>
```

Someone have an idea ? when I go to suggest with undefined it's tell me that my value is undefined but this value is define line 25 by my class CellName in my page.

Comment: if you add more information, it would be easier to help you. In this code, you work on the html structure, and we have to imagine it?

Comment: The search function search($(".cellName")); may

Comment: also you did not add all lines in this code. the function is missing closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
$(this).val();
```

`this` is not defined, as you call `search` without binding `this`.

Instead do:

```
$(cells).val();
```

Comment: thank you, so if I understand correctly the function is not called only when we call it but it's checked since the beginning ? am I right ? :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: 'this' isn't defined because the function is readed before be called or something similar ?

Comment: No, `this` is not defined because the function is called without a dot notation. It is called as just a plain function; not as a method. If you want to bind `this`, you can do `search.call($(".cellName"))`, or define a proper jQuery plug-in with `$.fn.search = function() { ...`, and then `$(".cellName").search()`. Lot's of possibilities.